# Oracle Insert from TH Date Format

Tags: oracle, date, format

I have the Data in the date formats of

2nd November 2010
15th Mar 2013  -- and so on.

I need to pick up these data and insert into the field of type DATE.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select to_char(sysdate,'ddth Month YYYY','NLS_DATE_language=American') from dual`

output:
19th November  2014

`select to_date('15th Mar 2013','dd"th" Mon YYYY','NLS_DATE_language=American') from dual`
used to trans varchar to date format.

Hope helps you.

Comment: It gives an error
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

on select to_date('15th Mar 2013','ddth Mon YYYY','NLS_DATE_language=American') from dual

Comment: Please try to_date('15th Mar 2013','dd"th" Mon YYYY','NLS_DATE_language=American')

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast the string to a date with the appropriate format mask:

```
insert into your_table values (
    to_date('2nd November 2010', 'ddth Month YYYY')
)
```

The documentation has a complete list of format models.  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210).

However, you have a problem because your input has different formats.  We cannot use the same mask to match NOVEMBER and MAR; the second date requires a mask of `'ddth Mar YYYY'`.

So you will need to write a function which catches `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` and applies a different mask; depending on the quality of your input data you may need to have several of these.  This situation is common with applications which don't use strong data-typing, and so demand data cleansing when they interact with more rigourous systems.

Comment: <nitpick>I'd replace *cast* with *convert* since CAST also exists in Oracle and behaves not quite the same way as to_date</nitpick>